# How to avoid the splitting of my jeans in the crotch area?

Tags: clothing

I don't really walk a lot. I use a bike as my transport means, but even before riding it, I use to tear my jeans quite soon, for instance as in this picture. They usually split sooner as 18 months with the following approximate frequency of use: I use them 4 times per month, i.e. 4x12x1.5=72 times were they worn; I washed them like once a month, i.e. washing them 18 times. That's the only spot my jeans are actually worn out, whence I don't want to throw them.

There are some hints as how to [repair them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfEc-lceKCY) but I'd like to know, if it's possible to avoid the formation of those holes.

[image]

Comment: It is material fatigue....according to my knowledge no help there. Most likely it is related to the way you are wearing jeans, walking driving bike etc.Things which are really hard to correct. I had the same issue, I found good tailor who fix it perfectly, plus 15 months isn't short life span for a pair of jeans :)

Comment: You're kind of stuck with buying jeans that aren't pre-aged or putting bike shorts on top.

Comment: Few jeans will last much longer than that with regular wear. It is a high wear area and I don't think much can be done besides washing them as little as possible and having many pairs to wear so that you aren't wearing them consecutive days.

Comment: The best solution is to change to a recumbent cycle, but that is going a bit far for most people. Since I lay back on the bike I have not had damaged trousers at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The holes develop for three reasons:

1. The pants are being stretched excessively.
2. The seat is rubbing on the pants.
3. The fabric is not sufficiently durable.

I ride a bike to work, so know from experience. Cheap, thin, coarse-weave polyester fabric is best. It is cool and doesn't hold water when you get hot and sweat. Not being jeans they are a bit looser and the fabric holds up better than denim. Such are surprisingly inexpensive costing less than jeans if one looks around. They can be bought at places like blair.com. I have several pairs from there lasting several years of daily bike riding. Riding a bike regularly requires a change in clothing style to facilitate comfortable riding.

The seat can be changed. Harder seats work better than soft ones for several reasons, and you are best off getting a thin racing-style seat with a small bit of springiness to it. A racing-style seat will cause less wear to clothing and offers more comfort.

Comment: Could someone please provide us with links to one or two examples of these polyester garments — cheaper than jeans — which Subjectivist has mentioned? At Walmart, I can buy an inexpensive pair of jeans for no more than $20-$30.

Comment: @subjectivist the link is dead by now.

Answer (score 1):

[This other answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/5537/1399) is correct, and I want to elaborate on one of the points raised there.

> The fabric is not sufficiently durable.

Most jeans are made of 100% cotton, so they aren't very durable. It's wisest to choose **pants or shorts which are more durable**.

For example, you can wear:

- **Cotton/polyester blend jeans**. (Even just a little bit of polyester might help make the fabric last significantly longer.)
- Or **dress pants**, which are made of polyester and/or wool. (Some are dry-clean-only, but most are machine-washable. I prefer wearing black or dark-gray dress pants; these colors seem to go fine with a T-shirt, a hoodie, and sneakers.)
- Or **track pants**, which are made of nylon or polyester.
- Or **athletic shorts**, which are made of polyester. (Don't choose casual shorts which are made of cotton.)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong; but, I'm never in doubt.

I think the problem with clothing failures such as this are due to poor-fit of the article for the person. If a person splits their pants, it is because the pants were too tight. With casual wear, the seams might be strong enough to transfer the stress failure to the fabric itself. Sometimes the seam will fail, sometimes the stitching. In every case, the article will be too small.

Mass-produced clothing patterns are made for an average (not normal) body shape. The standard-sized article may or may not conform to the shape of our body resulting in one or more stress areas. Ideally, standard shapes can be altered to custom fit us. The result is a stress free fit that will wear evenly, all things considered.

As evidence, examine your clothing. Notice that the pieces that show undue localized wear will be tight-fitting. It is no coincidence that loose-fitting clothes will never show the kinds of failures for what you now blame on the fabric, its care, the activity, and the brand (cut).

Some might say, 'lose weight,' but that is misdirected. Rather, try loosening-up a bit and even bicycling every day won't show appreciable wear.

Good luck.